# Issue running rsync from windows server 2016 to windows server 2016

Tags: rsync, windows-server-2016

I'm trying without success to copy files from one windows host to another using either `cygwin` or powershell and the rsync.exe. On the windows host I want to send the copy I have `openssh` installed, I can telnet on 22 to it, and can send files to it via scp. But, when I try to copy files to it from either a windows or linux machine, I get the following error:

```
'rsync' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.1]
```

This is the command I use to copy from powershell:

```
.\rsync.exe -avzh --stats -P -e C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\rsync\ssh.exe rs
ync.html 'administrator@ip:C:\\'
```

When I run the same command, but try to copy to a CentOS 7 machine, I only change `administrator@ip:C:\\` to `root@ip:/root/` and it works.

If you have any idea what the issue could be, or you need any other info, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I cannot answer your question directly however can give you a just as good workaround, in my experience, while Cygwin can give you a good platform to be able to use Linux commands on windows. Keep in mind windows is not Linux.

Most Linux commands have a windows counterpart, yes some are not one-liners, however have you looked at robocopy?

Robocopy - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy

Comes installed and can be used with powershell.

Comment: Thank you for your response! 

Unfortunately I cannot use robocopy for this task as it does not copy files that are currently open, of which I will have a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For your consideration: I built a convenient OpenSSH package that includes rsync:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/CygSSH

It uses Cygwin v3 so it doesn't require a dedicated service account (the service runs as `SYSTEM`).

The intent is to provide a convenient packaging of OpenSSH and rsync that is (relatively) convenient to install and use on Windows machines, so it has some defaults and capabilities that are more Windows-centric:

- Installer supports silent installation and adding to the system path
- Windows PowerShell is the remote interactive shell
- It creates an SSH Users local group for authentication and sets that by default in `sshd_config`; nested groups are supported (e.g., if you want to manage the membership via GPO)
- It supports granting sftp-only access to accounts
- It includes rsync

The package requires Vista/Server 2008 or newer and Windows PowerShell 2.0 or later.